# Loop won't break I dont know why

Tags: python-3.x

```py
import random, string

name= input("What is your name: ")

print("Hello ", name + " welcome to a game of hangman")

word1 = "hello ".strip()
all_letters_1= ([*word1])

word2 = "batman ".strip()
all_letters_2= ([*word2])

word3 = "rashford".strip()
all_letters_3= ([*word3])


words = all_letters_1 , all_letters_2 , all_letters_3
print(words)


word_list = []


rand_word = random.choice(words)
print(rand_word)`your text`
guesses = ['_'] * len(rand_word)
correct_letters = 0

while True:
    for letter in rand_word:
        x = input("Guess a letter")

        if x.lower() == "quit":
            print("".join(word_list))
            break

        if len(x)== 1:
            if x.lower() == rand_word[len(word_list)]:
                word_list.append(x.lower())
            else:
                print("Incorrect Guess")
        rm_brackets = "".join(word_list)
        print(str(rm_brackets))

        if sorted(rm_brackets) == sorted(rand_word):
            print("You guessed all the letters correctly")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop will not break, because you are breaking out of the for loop and not the while loop.

As for solutions.

- I don't think you need the while loop. Remove it.
- Put the loops into a function and instead of calling break call return (this will end the entire function).
- Change while true to be a while var, and then set var = false before you break.
- Break the while loop by calling break outside of the for loop.